# How to set up multiple combine timer publishers?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Here I have a simple SwiftUI project which has two timer publishers which are set to fire every 1 second and 2 seconds respectively.

The *expected* behavior is that the first label would update every second and the second label would update every 2 seconds. However what actually happens is only the first label updates every second and the second label remains at 0 indefinitely.

I know it's possible to make multiple timers using `Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:)` by simply making new variables of those timer instances but it doesn't seem to work the same way with these publishers.

How can I make both timers work?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var counter1 = 0
    @State private var counter2 = 0
    
    let timer1 = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    let timer2 = Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            Text(String(counter1))
                .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
            Text(String(counter2))
                .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
        }
        .padding()
        .onReceive(timer1) {_ in
            counter1 += 1
        }
        .onReceive(timer2) {_ in
            counter2 += 2
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working as you expected in ios 14.2 /xcode 12.2

Comment: I see that's interesting. I initially was writing for macOS SwiftUI app and so I discovered that it was not working properly. Would you mind trying this again but this time create a macOS SwiftUI application? Just for reference I am running macOS 11.0.1 /Xcode 12.2

Comment: Might not be the cause of your problem, but you're doing it wrong - you should not store publishers within the View - the View can be discarded and recreated multiple times by SwiftUI, and when that happens you get fresh new publishers.

Comment: Okay but that’s a little vague for me. What would be the right way to do it then? Because I got this from hacking with swift which in general is a good reliable resource.

Comment: Recommended approach is to store both the publishers and the counters into a (View)Model, and reference that either via `@StateObject`, or `@ObservedObject`. Creating the publishers in the View is unreliable because you don't have control over the view lifecycle.

Comment: Can you possible link some code to that approach? The internet is pretty scarce when it comes to swiftUI timer publishers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SwiftUI your view is a transitory struct.  Ie the system remakes the views all the time and throws away the old ones.  The View, therefore should not be holding the references to the timers (you will be making new timers and dropping old ones all the time).  Make a viewModel and store the values there.  In general don't store things on the view that are not in a property wrapper or passed in through the initializer.

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published private(set) var first = 0
  @Published private(set) var second = 0
  private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
  func start() {
    Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
      .autoconnect()
      .scan(0) { accumulated, _ in accumulated + 1 }
      .assign(to: \.first, on: self)
      .store(in: &subscriptions)
    Timer.publish(every: 2, on: .main, in: .common)
      .autoconnect()
      .scan(0) { accumulated, _ in accumulated + 1 }
      .assign(to: \.second, on: self)
      .store(in: &subscriptions)
  }
  func stop() {
    subscriptions.removeAll()
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(String(describing: viewModel.first))
      Text(String(describing: viewModel.second))
    }
    .onAppear { viewModel.start() }
    .onDisappear { viewModel.stop() }
  }
}
```