# macOS SwiftUI SceneView with multiple onReceive() handlers seem to block each other

Tags: swiftui, scenekit, combine

I've got a SceneView that has two `.onReceive()` handlers. One responds to a 30 Hz timer I set up to animate the camera movement based on some space mouse input values, the second responds to changes in the space mouse input values to update the local state.

What I'm finding is that the timer fires as you would expect, 30 times/second, until input starts coming in from the space mouse, at which point the timer's onReceive stops being called. Once I stop manipulating the space mouse, its input stops flowing.

This makes for unusable camera control. Now, I may be doing it wrong, but I'm pretty limited with what the SwiftUI SceneView has to offer, and this seems like a pretty broken behavior for Combine.

Am I missing something obvious?

```swift
struct
PerlinTerrainGeneratorView: View
{
    @EnvironmentObject  private var         multiAxisInput      :   MultiAxisDevice
    @State              private var         multiAxisState      :   MultiAxisState          =   MultiAxisState()
    
    let         updateTimer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0 / 30.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var
    body: some View
    {
        SceneView(scene: self.scene, pointOfView: self.cameraNode, delegate: PerlinTerrainGeneratorRendererDelegate(view: self))
            .onReceive(self.updateTimer) { inTimer in
                if let ea = self.cameraNode
                {
                    debugLog("roll: \(self.multiAxisState.roll)")
                    let qq = GLKQuaternionMakeWithAngleAndAxis(Float(self.multiAxisState.roll) * 0.01, 0, 0, 1)
                    let q = SCNQuaternion(qq.x, qq.y, qq.z, qq.w)
                    ea.localRotate(by: q)
                }
            }
            .onReceive(self.multiAxisInput.$state) { inState in
                self.multiAxisState = inState
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've edited the question.

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65696728/9221705